# Query 2 sum in 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

table a

```
column id    : a a b b
column total : 1 2 1 3
```

how can i show? in one table without use compute

```
a 3 7
b 4 7
```

Comment: Hmmm. what happened with your last edit?  Is it just the formatting that went wrong?  Or did you actually change the question?

Comment: @BudiDharma: You should use the previous edit. That was more helpful to understand the table structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `group by` to sum each id's total. Do a sub-select to count total:

```
select id,
       sum(total) as total,
       (select sum(total) from a) as totalall
from a
group by id
```

Comment: thx jarlh its work. i confuse with 2 select and 2 sum haha. nice

Comment: Great to hear. Do also take a look at sstan's answer, which may be better for SQL Server users. (But I suppose my answer is more portable.)

Answer (score 2):

Using window functions with a distinct, it can be simply expressed like this:

```
select distinct id,
       sum(Total) over(partition by id) total,
       Sum(Total) over () total_all
  from mytable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3941b/2)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `OUTER APPLY`. You could also set a variable to the sum of the table and call that variable.

```
select a.id, sum(a.total) as total, b.Grand as GrandTotal
from tablea a
outer apply
(select sum(total) as Grand from tablea) b
group by a.id
```